# How can I handle multiple pages for saving user data in 3 steps where each step is a new interface then save them together?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, interface

I am building an app which should capture user's data in 4 basic steps 1. Bio Data, 2. Parental Details, 3. Education data then 4. Uploads of ID and picture. I would like this to be a 4 step process where you can not go to step 2 if step 1 is not validated. How can I implement this in flutter? Help

Comment: You're building a wizard. Create a model class and pass it from one page to the next.

Comment: @TedHenry Do you have a link for reference maybe it will give me a rough idea.

Comment: No i don't have a reference. If you know how to create a class and pass an object from one page to the next, you're in! Give it a try and post your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Stepper widget that provides this kind of functionality,

for usage refer [this](https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-16-stepper-485ad8d1a248)

for the widget documentation refer [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks